# When is CMPCTBLOCK message sent in High Bandwidth Relaying?

Tags: protocol, compact-blocks

In the [Compact Blocks FAQ](https://bitcoincore.org/en/2016/06/07/compact-blocks-faq/), particularly, the High Bandwidth Relaying diagram attached below, the CMPCTBLOCK message is sent by node A when receiving block is not yet completed.

The description says: `When a new block arrives, Node A performs some basic validation (such as validating the block header) and then automatically begins sending the header, shortened txids, and predicted missing transaction (as described above) to Node B.`

Is this really true? As I am checking the latest Bitcoin Core code, I see that INV/HEADERS/CMPTCBLOCK messages of a new block are [**only relayed once the block tip is updated**](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/net_processing.cpp#L1557-L1590) (i.e., new `hash` is pushed to v`BlockHashesToAnnounce`).

Isn't that this means the CMPCTBLOCK message is sent only after the new block is fully validated (non-contextual and contextual checks)?

[image]